# localization of a module and annihilators

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

I've just started reading on my own about localizations of modules. I've run into a difficulty as follows:

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, $M$ an $R$-module, $S\subseteq R$ a multiplicative system containing no zero-divisors. Suppose there exists a nonzero $v\in M$ and an $s\in S$ such that $sv=0$. Consider the element $v/s\in S^{-1}M$. The product $s(v/s)$ can be calculated in two different ways:
$$s\,\frac{v}{s} = \frac{sv}{s} = \frac{0}{s} = 0$$
and
$$s\,\frac{v}{s} = \frac{s}{s}\,v = v.$$
But then $v=0$, contradicting the fact that $v\neq 0$.

As a concrete example, consider the case $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, and $S=\mathbb{Z}\setminus(q)$,  where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Then $p\in S$, and $p\,\overline{1}=\overline{p}=0$, yet $\overline{1}\neq 0$.

What am I missing?

Comment: $(s/s)\cdot v$ doesn't mean anything (this is the multiplication of an element of $S^{-1}M$ by an element of $M$...); what you meant is $s\cdot (v/s) = (s/s) \cdot (v/1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$sv=0$ means that $\frac{v}{1}=0$ in $S^{-1} M$. But this doesn't mean that $v=0$ in $M$. In fact, the kernel of $M \to S^{-1} M$ consists *precisely* of those elements which are annihilated by an element of $S$. So your observations don't contradict at all, they show exactly what's typical for localizations.